# Google Analytics - Track 'No results found' page with generic URL

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Im looking for some advice on Google Analytics - I have a 'No results found' page with a generic URL that I want to track. I would like to see how many times this page is hit and what the url parameters are.

I have setup the site search within Analytics, but this only tells me what searches have been submitted. Not if there has actually been any results or they have hit the 'No results found' page.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You can pass a custom dimension to capture the number search results that show up on the search page. Some tips here <http://mixedanalytics.com/blog/number-search-results-google-analytics-gtm/?

Comment: the no results found page is something like 404 page?
Do you see this message on any of the page where the details are not found? Just wondering if you are using Google Tag Manager on site?
Asking questions in order to reply according to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [virtual page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages?hl=en). Just make sure you execute this code when there are no results at the page (change [search-variable] with the actual term that has been searched).

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/search/no-results/[search-variable]');
```

If you have no access to the code, [you can use Google Tag Manager](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/09/10/fire-virtual-pageview-google-tag-manager/).